# How to exactly see the reason of Windows shutdown/hang/reboot?

Tags: windows, freeze, reboot

PC (Windows 10) reboots randomly (and all temperatures are within normal limits, so it's not because overheat).
Is there a way to see what exactly caused it?

Comment: It might be in the Event Log. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-can-you-find-the-cause-of-unexpected-shutdown/54cf6947-0cc2-4719-ab47-9f9cb989de8f

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out why PC just restarted for no reason](https://superuser.com/q/767143/173513), [Diagnosing the cause of frequent reboots](https://superuser.com/q/1118428/173513), [Stop Computer From Automatically Rebooting Overnight](https://superuser.com/q/222377/173513), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your PC is probably automatically rebooting on BSOD (Blue Screen of Death).  If you disable automatic restarting, you will be able to see the specific error code on the blue screen.  To disable automatic restart:

1. "Win+R" to open the Run dialog
2. Type "sysdm.cpl", then "Enter" to open the System properties window
3. Click on the "Advanced" tab, then click on the "Settings..." button in the "Startup and Recovery" section
4. Under "System failure", un-check "Automatically restart", then click "OK" to close the "Startup and Recovery" window and click "OK" on the "System Properties" window

Next time your PC crashes, it should remain on the BSOD until your press the physical power/reset button on your PC.  You can write down the error code and start troubleshooting what is causing your PC to crash.

Comment: This information can also be obtained by looking in the System event log for event ID 1001 source: BugCheck