# Computer shutting down overnight

Tags: windows, bug

This happens occasionally. When I turn it on (by pressing the power button normally not to start up) the log-in screen has changed to the default, which is how I know it happened.
When I log in I see that all my apps (including with unsaved work) have been closed. When I investigate by looking up Update History there has been no update. When I check the log-in screen again it has changed back to form.
Why s this happening and how can this blithe destruction of my work be prevented?

Comment: Linking to a related question https://superuser.com/questions/222377/stop-computer-from-automatically-rebooting-overnight?rq=1

Comment: Is this on a laptop or desktop? Is it a corporate machine, managed by IT? Is mains power interrupted? Didi you use Hibernate (which saves data, even if power is lost), or Sleep (which does *not*)?